# Golang upload image to GCS with specific path

Tags: image, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sdk

I had stuck with Google Cloud Storage and os.create()

This is my example code

```
func upload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     // some process request msg, decode base64 to image byte
    // create image file in current directory with os.create()
    // 
    path := os.create("shop_logo.jpeg")
    bucket := client.Bucket("myBucket")
    write := bucket.Object(path).NewWriter(ctx)
     
}
```

Create file with directory

```
func upload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     // some process request msg, decode base64 to image byte
    // create image file in current directory with os.create()
    // 
    path := os.create("home/../project/repo/shop_logo.jpeg") //absolute path
    bucket := client.Bucket("myBucket")
    write := bucket.Object(path).NewWriter(ctx)
     
}
```

Acutally everything it work, like `mybucket/shop_logo.jpeg`
But I want to organize the bucket path such as `mybucket/shop_v1/shop_logo.jpeg`
But the I used the `os.create()` like `os.create("shop_v1/shop_logo.jpeg)`
It's can't work, look like this function can't create the folder.
but when I used the **Absolute Path** It's work. like `os.create("/home/project/shop_v1/shop_logo.jpeg)`
The problem is `bucket.Object("path/to/image_file")` is require the path of file.
So If I used the **Absolute Path** to upload it.
My bucket will be `myBucket/home/project/shop_v1/shop_logo.jpeg` .

But the thing that I expect it is `mybucket/shop_v1/shop_logo.jpeg`

Anyone have idea?

Comment: os.Create has nothing to do with uploading a file to GCS, and the code you show doesn't call it anyway. It's unclear to me what you're asking.

Comment: @Peter Hi, Correct the os.Create doesn't do anything with upload, but it effect to the **PATH** on my bucket GCS, I just updated the code. Please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I just found the `os.create()` can create directory also.

It my fault like this

```
inputPath := "/shop_v1/shop_logo.jpeg"
os.create(inputPath)
```

The application will error, can't find blah blah.
I just have to **remove the first slash** of inputPath variable

```
inputPath := "shop_v1/shop_logo.jpeg"
os.create(inputPath)
```

Now it work!.